# XSLT - Sum all the attribute values

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Need to sum all the attribute value without actually hard coding the attribute names. Below is the example having 2 attributes. The scenario is that there could be n number of attributes which is not known before hand.

```
<Books>
 <Book a="10" b="20"  />
 <Book a="30" b="40"  />
</Books>
```

Output:

```
<analysis>
  <a>40</a>
  <b>60</b>
</analysis>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple exercise in [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <analysis>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Book/@*" group-by="name()">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group())" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </analysis>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was trying out adding name() to the sum parameter which did not work. Using grouping really makes things look clean and simpler. Thanks for the quick reply.